# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape various tables and combine in a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A page contains a table of links, each link contains a table relevant to the link (a subject). Create a list of these links to pass to the function called `scrapeTable` which then takes the table and stores it in a CSV file. A directory of files are created for each subject which are then merged into one master file.

I'm looking for some feedback/criticism/improvements to a piece of code I've written.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

def scrapeTable(url):
    r = s.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml") 

    #get page header
    title = soup.find('h4', 'otherTablesSubTitle')
    subject_name = title.contents[0]

   #get table with 'tablesorter' as name
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablesorter'})

    #open file using page header    
    with open('C:/' + subject_name + '.csv', 'ab') as f:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            headers = []
            for item in soup.find_all('th'):
                headers.append(item.contents[0])

        #because some pages don't follow exact format, rename any instances of Institution to University
        for idx, h in enumerate(headers):
            if 'Institution' in h:
                headers[idx] = 'University'

        csvwriter.writerow(headers)

        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            cells = [c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in row.findAll('td')]

            csvwriter.writerow(cells)

    #get third index to use as id for pd.melt           
    header_id = headers[2]
    #remove third index to use remaining as values for pd.melt
    headers.pop(2)

    #denormalise the table and insert subject name at beginning
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/' + subject_name + '.csv')
    a = pd.melt(df, id_vars=header_id, value_vars=headers, var_name='Measure', value_name='Value')
    a.insert(0, 'Subject', subject_name)

    a.to_csv('C:/' + subject_name + '.csv', sep=',', index=False)

#details to post to login form
payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}

#use with to close session after finished
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('websitelogin', data=payload)
    r = s.get('website')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    #get list of links (subjects)
    links = []
    for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        if 'imported' in anchor['href']:
            links.append('link' + anchor['href'])

    #for each link, call scrapeTable and pass link through          
    for item in links:
        scrapeTable(item)



#this merges all the files together into one file called final      
path = 'C:/'
allCSV = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
CSVList = []
for file in allCSV:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0)
    CSVList.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(CSVList)
frame.to_csv('C:/final.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Code Style

- follow the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), in particular - fix the imports order, use the `lower_case_with_udnerscores` variable and function naming style (e.g. `scrapeTable` and `CSVList` are violations)

#### HTML parsing

- I think you are over-using the `.contents` attribute. Consider switching to [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)
- look into using [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which is, generally, a more concise way to locate the elements. For example, you can replace `table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablesorter'})` with `table = soup.select_one('table.tablesorter')`. Or, you can replace:

  ```
  links = []
  for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
      if 'imported' in anchor['href']:
          links.append('link' + anchor['href'])
  ```

  with:

  ```
  links = ['link' + anchor['href'] for anchor in soup.select("a[href*=imported]")]
  ```

  where `*=` means "contains".